# Mac OS: Catalina: unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

Tags: python, xcode, macos, gcc, pip

MAC OS Catalina(10.15.1) seems to have created some problems for building code that uses gcc. I am trying to build a python application which is running into the following error.

```html
Running setup.py install for pdftotext: started
    Running setup.py install for pdftotext: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yzaiz97e/pdftotext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-67h0h5_9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    WARNING: pkg-config not found--guessing at poppler version.
             If the build fails, install pkg-config and try again.
    /usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pdftotext' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c pdftotext.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pdftotext.o -Wall
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

gcc is  definitely installed on the system but somehow not visible to pip installer.

```
which gcc

/usr/bin/gcc


packaging % gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

xcode-select --install                          
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Any help to debug the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments or similar?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile no. I am building a docker container and using a requirements.txt file to install python packages.

Comment: So where is that `gcc` being executed? In your container? Or in your host? Because the problem may be `gcc` is not contained in the image you are pulling... And you are checking in host.